# Python- how to install pyvttbl in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anova

I tried installing it using !pip install

```
!pip install pyvttbl
```

and it gives me this message

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyvttbl 
Requirement already satisfied: dictset
Requirement already satisfied: pystaggrelite3
```

However, when I import it as

```
import pyvttbl as pt
```

it gives me

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-89ef5f67d382> in <module>()
----> 1 import pyvttbl as pt

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyvttbl\__init__.py in <module>()
      8 # This software is funded in part by NIH Grant P20 RR016454.
      9 
---> 10 from base import PyvtTbl, DataFrame
     11 
     12 from misc import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base'
```

When I try to install base as

```
!pip install base
```

it gives me this

```
    Collecting base
Using cached base-1.0.4.tar.gz
        Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-u1xkw0lp\base\setup.py", line 40, in <module>
            LONG_DESCRIPTION = read("README.rst")
          File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-u1xkw0lp\base\setup.py", line 21, in read
            return codecs.open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()
          File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
            return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
        UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 5: character maps to <undefined>
```

Can someone help me understand the problem?

Comment: what python distro are you using? anaconda?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Background

Pyvttbl is no longer actively maintained which is why you are having some difficulty.

I assume that you are using python 3.x and it seems to me that pyvttbl will only work for python 2.7 right now.

## Solution

#### NOTE: only applies to systems running jupyter notebook through Anaconda.

I managed to get this to work in my python 2.7 environment. However I could not reproduce a working install for in a new env. So I exported my py27 env as a `.yml` file that you can clone through these steps;

1) Download and unzip the `.yml` env from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/draperjames/8215dd2b7af117cdbac25c73aa9070b3)

2) cd to the location of the unzipped `.yml` file.

3) Create the clone of my py27 env using the following command;

```
conda env create -f py27.yml
```

4) Once conda finishes the install then activate the env;

```
activate py27
```

5) Then this env to your list of jupyter notebook kernels with the following;

```
ipython kernel install --name py27
```

Now when you start jupyter notebook you can choose to create a `py27` notebook when you click the new button. After that you should be able to run pyttbl.

Please comment below if you are still having issues.

Comment: Thank you so so much for all the effort, I did all the steps but still on my jupyter notebook I am still having the same issue :s

Comment: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-yyguw62p\base\

Comment: @rsc05 where did this error occur? were you able to create the py27 env?

Comment: Now it work, after I restarted my computer :s Thank you so much James :)